# Undefined variables in well defined loops

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I wonder if you can set me straight on some javascript I'm a little confused with. The code is over here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbd5k5zh/. The piece of code that escapes me is:

```
[...]
// Locate this entity at the given position on the grid
  at: function(x, y) {
    if (x === undefined && y === undefined) {
      return { x: this.x/Game.map_grid.tile.width, y: this.y/Game.map_grid.tile.height }
    } else {...}
  }
```

If I'm in a nested loop for instance:

```
for(x=0;x<24;x++):
  for(y=0;y<16;y++)
```

so `x,y` are clearly well defined and generating cartesian co-ords like thus:

```
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)... (23,0)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1)... (23,1)
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2)       .
.        .              .
.             .         .
.                  .    .
(0,14)(1,14)(2,14)
(0,15)(1,15)(2,15)...(23,15)
```

How will `x` or `y` ever become undefined? Moreover, I don't see where/how

```
return { x: this.x/Game.map_grid.tile.width === this.x/16
```

`this.x` becomes initialised? I realise it's an edge case but struggle to come up with a scenario where it may be used.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use `this.x` and `this.y` over just using `x` and `y`?

Comment: @sWW likely it has to do with `crafty.js` and whatever properties the the Grid object has...

Comment: @serakfalcon just seems a bit odd to check if `x` and `y` are defined then not call them

Comment: Checking whether `x` and `y` are defined is just checking whether they  are passed as parameters upon calling the `at` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of checking if the arguments are undefined is do give 2 different behaviors (APIs) to the function.

If you call `obj.at()` (no arguments, i.e the body of the function will see the arguments as `undefined`), this function acts as a getter: it returns current coordinates.

If you call `obj.at(x,y)`, this function acts more as a setter (sets the current position), from what I have seen. This is the case of the code in your post.

Whether designing functions API that way is good practice or not is debatable; your confusion is an argument in favor of the no.

Comment: Just to pick-up on that point. Assuming I call `obj.at()` (with no arguments) where then are the values for `this.x, this.y` coming from if they're undefined? The loop variables?

Comment: when calling `obj.at()`, `this.x` and `this.y` resolve to `obj.x` and `obj.y` in the body of `obj.at`. But you must understand that `x`(the argument) has nothing to do with `this.x` (property of object `this` with name "x").

Comment: Well explained @ Valentin. I just did some logging to the console: `[...] else if (Math.random() < 0.06) {
                    // Place a bush entity at the current tile  
                    Crafty.e('Bush').at(x, y);  
                    console.log(Crafty.e('Bush').at());  
                }` Assuming `Math.random()` occurs `n` times then my log shows `Object {x=0, y=0}`, `n` times. Or for each occurrence of `Crafty.e('Bush').at()`. The quotient of `0/16` is zero for all `x & y` resp, moreover it doesn't give me the current co-ords as I progress through the loop?

Comment: @AndrewCookson Sorry, didn't get your comment question.

Comment: OK, no worries. I'll leave that for now. Thanks for your help.